# Unexpected lme result using level-2 predictor in the random part of the model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

Level-2- predictors (`Z`) allow for modelling the level-1 slopes. They do not vary within a level-2 unit. However, it is possible to include them in the random part, as illustrated in the following simulation:

```
  set.seed(123)

  k   =  30   # no. of cluster (level 2)
  n   = 100   # no. of individ (level 1)

  t0  = 200   # sd of intercepts
  t1  =   9   # sd of slopes
  eps =  25   # sd of residuals

  g00 = 500   # mean intercept
  g10 =   2   # mean slope

  g01 =   4   # 2nd level slope for intcpts b0 on Z
  g11 =   8   # 2nd level slope for slopes b1 on Z

  x = matrix(rnorm(n*k,50,10),n,k)  # cols = level-2 units
  e = matrix(rnorm(n*k,0,eps),n,k)
  z = rnorm(k,5,1)           # level-2 predictor
  g = rep(1:k,each=n)

  u0 = rnorm(k,0,t0)
  u1 = rnorm(k,0,t1)

  b0 = g00 + g01*z + u0
  b1 = g10 + g11*z + u1

  y = matrix(NA,n,k)
  for (j in 1:k) y[,j] = b0[j] + b1[j]*x[,j] + e[,j]

  d0 = data.frame(grp=g,xx=as.vector(x),yy=as.vector(y),zz=rep(z,each=n))

  mod1 = nlme::lme(data=d0, fixed=yy~xx*zz, 
                   random=~xx   |grp,control=list(opt="optim"))
  mod2 = nlme::lme(data=d0, fixed=yy~xx*zz, 
                   random=~xx*zz|grp,control=list(opt="optim")) # !?

  summary(mod1)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: d0 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  28266.82 28314.86 -14125.41

Random effects:
 Formula: ~xx | grp
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr  
(Intercept) 162.09849 (Intr)
xx           11.07477 0.303 
Residual     24.90749       

Fixed effects: yy ~ xx * zz 
               Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 492.8279 194.81763 2968  2.529688  0.0115
xx           -0.5032  13.26995 2968 -0.037917  0.9698
zz            5.4064  38.22534   28  0.141435  0.8885
xx:zz         8.6747   2.60364 2968  3.331774  0.0009
 Correlation: 
      (Intr) xx     zz    
xx     0.300              
zz    -0.988 -0.297       
xx:zz -0.297 -0.988  0.300

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-3.279494751 -0.656165706  0.007919223  0.664298025  3.510426065 

Number of Observations: 3000
Number of Groups: 30 


>   summary(mod2)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: d0 
       AIC   BIC    logLik
  28280.92 28371 -14125.46

Random effects:
 Formula: ~xx * zz | grp
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr              
(Intercept) 86.334818 (Intr) xx    zz   
xx           5.406595 0.280             
zz          15.865643 0.977  0.445      
xx:zz        1.143709 0.224  0.998 0.393
Residual    24.905938                   

Fixed effects: yy ~ xx * zz 
               Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 447.2072 201.17028 2968  2.223028  0.0263
xx           -4.5221  13.54937 2968 -0.333749  0.7386
zz           14.5183  40.35761   28  0.359742  0.7217
xx:zz         9.4775   2.72278 2968  3.480830  0.0005
 Correlation: 
      (Intr) xx     zz    
xx     0.331              
zz    -0.989 -0.328       
xx:zz -0.328 -0.989  0.332

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-3.277727904 -0.655321281  0.008241865  0.664324708  3.510659067 

Number of Observations: 3000
Number of Groups: 30
```

Hence, my question: *Why does mod2 work?* To my understanding, the model should
not be identified for the lack of variation of `z|j`  (j = level-2 unit index).
(Interstingly, mod2 would not attain convergence with the the default optimizer,
so is it just a method artifact? Or, is the simulation concept flawed?).
Although the two results are fairly similar, I would like to understand the
conceptual difference of the two models.

NB: The same is true for the lme4 routine using the following calls:

```
  lme4::lmer(yy~xx*zz + (xx|grp),data=d0)
  lme4::lmer(yy~xx*zz + (xx*zz|grp),data=d0)
```

Again, the second model issues an optimizer warning, supporting my belief that something odd is going on... but what?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's pretty close to non-identified; the correlation between the random effect intercept term and the random slope for zz is 0.977, and between the xx and xx:zz terms it's 0.998. I played with different random seeds and sizes of data sets and for one run got this error, which I think is more like the error you would have expected.

```
Error in solve.default(pdMatrix(a, factor = TRUE)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.27837e-18
```

I suspect (but am not sure) that the reason this doesn't happen every time is computational, and that these routines don't check ahead of time for cases where this might be true.

All the more reason to know what you're asking the computer to do, and not ask it to do things that don't make sense. :) It seems to me that your intuition here was spot-on.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron! R obviously would not check for nonsensical input, as the following example shows: `lm(y~x, data=data.frame(y=rnorm(10),x=42))`